# Given two different classes which refer a common class(Test.java) in their definition, How many times ClassLoader#loadClass(Test) gets called?

Tags: java, classloader

Given two different classes which refer a common class(Test.java) in their definitions, 
How many times [ClassLoader#loadClass(Test)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#loadClass(java.lang.String)) gets called?

```
ClassA    {
Test t = new Test();
}

ClassB    {
Test t = new Test();
}
```

I want to understand if a classloader has already loaded class(Test), and in another class(ClassB) same class is referred, 
does the jvm call [ClassLoader#loadClass(Test)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#loadClass(java.lang.String)) again or not? if not, how does it check if class is already loaded by same classloader?

Comment: This is well explained in the doc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#loadClass%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4

Comment: so it will call loadClass() 2 times? for second call, it will return the result of findLoadedClass(String). thx